# How to migrate from rosbuild to catkin

Tags: ros, local-planner, eband-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a beginner about a migration. If you are familiar with migration from rosbuild to catkin, Could you teach me how to migrate from rosbuild to catkin.
This is an example of eband_local_planner. I edited CMakeLists.txt as following.
Is this correct? Now I use ROS hydro on Ubuntu12.04.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(eband_local_planner)

# Before this can be catkinized, the control_toolbox needs to be catknized.

find_package(catkin REQUIRED 
        COMPONENTS
                        roscpp 
                        pluginlib 
                        nav_core
                        costmap_2d 
                        base_local_planner 
                        nav_msgs
                        geometry_msgs 
                        visualization_msgs 
                        tf
                        tf_conversions 
                        angles 
                        control_toolbox
                        actionlib 
                        eigen
)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED
    COMPONENTS
        thread
        )

find_package(Eigen REQUIRED)

include_directories(
    include
    ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
${EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
add_library(eband_local_planner
  src/conversions_and_types.cpp
  src/eband_action.cpp
  src/eband_local_planner.cpp
  src/eband_local_planner_ros.cpp
  src/eband_trajectory_controller.cpp
  src/eband_visualization.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(eband_local_planner 
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}    
${Boost_LIBRARIES}
)
install(TARGETS eband_local_planner
       LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
   )
install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
  PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
)
install(FILES blp_plugin.xml
DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
)
```

package.xml is written on this web( https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation_experimental/tree/hydro-devel/eband_local_planner).
If you have an experiment of catkinizing eband_local_planner, I want to know more information.
The reason I put this article is I wanted to resolve an error when I moved a turtlebot with eband_local_planner.
Actually, I have compiling error.

```
CMake Error at eband_local_planner/CMakeLists.txt:53 (install):
  install TARGETS given no LIBRARY DESTINATION for shared library target
  "eband_local_planner".
CMake Error at eband_local_planner/CMakeLists.txt:62 (install):
  install FILES given no DESTINATION!
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/167876/how-to-migrate-from-rosbuild-to-catkin/) by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 894 on 2014-05-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-05-21**:
Before catkinizing a package, Is it better to rosbuild the package of fuerte version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The master branch here is also catkinized, and this is the source repository: https://github.com/utexas-bwi/eband_local_planner

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-05-21**:
Thanks @ahendrix, Excuse me, may I ask you? does master mean stable?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-05-21**:
Branch names are set by the developer; you can usually guess which branches are stable by looking at all of the branch names, and how often they're updated: https://github.com/utexas-bwi/eband_local_planner/network . You can also look at tags, which are usually the released versions.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-05-21**:
In this case, it looks like changes are done on their devel branch and on feature branches, and releases are done from master.